# I have a list in which multiple Time-In or Time-Out , Break In or Break out

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angular

I have a list in which multiple Time-In  or Time-Out , Break In or Break out.
i want to calculate total duration from **Time-In to Time-Out**

Here is data.

```
const data = 
  [ { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '02:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time In'
    , comments                  : 'dgdfgdfg'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '03:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time Out'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '04:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Break In'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '05:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Break Out'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '06:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time In'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '07:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time Out'
    , comments                  : '232323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  ]
```

here is Input form
[![you can check input fields for better understanding][1]][1]

Note :
so first Time-in was 2:28 or Time-out 3:28  and hour will  be **1**.
after break-in or break out again  **Time-in is 6:28 or Time-out 7:28**  and hour will  be **1**.
**now hours is 2.**
Please any body suggest how I can get **total duration 2** in using JavaScript , Typescript.

Comment: ***here is Input form*** the image doesn't seem to be properly uploaded. Please re-upload the image.

Comment: What code have you attempted so far?

Comment: Pretty sure you posted this yesterday as well and it was closed because you showed no research effort.

Comment: First, change the time to seconds and you then can apply calculation in seconds. Second, if the time-in and time-out always in a consecutive pattern, you can just loop through the array and calculate their difference and store it in a total value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to determine the difference between two time strings (formatted as 'hh:mm').

```js
const tIN = '03:28'.split(`:`).map(Number);
const tOUT = '04:28'.split(`:`).map(Number);
let [now, then] = [new Date, new Date];
now.setHours(tIN[0]);
now.setMinutes(tIN[1]);
then.setHours(tOUT[0]);
then.setMinutes(tOUT[1]);
const diff = dateDiffCalc(then - now);
console.log(diff);

function dateDiffCalc(milliseconds) {
  const secs = Math.floor(Math.abs(milliseconds) / 1000);
  const mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  const hours = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  
  return {
    days: Math.floor(hours / 24),
    hours: hours % 24,
    minutes: mins % 60,
    seconds: secs % 60,
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks but i have multiple Time-In or multiple Time out in list.
i need only total duration of Total Time-In or Time Out

Comment: It's up to you to figure out a way to calculate the total.

Comment: [Hint](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rtvmei?file=index.js)